# modifying scrapy process request

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.loader.processors import Join,MapCompose
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "plus"
    start_urls = ['http://httpbin.org/anything']
    def __init__(self):
        scrapy.Spider.__init__(self)
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
        options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
        options.add_argument('--disable-browser-side-navigation')
        options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)


    def __del__(self):
        try:
            scrapy.Spider.__del__(self)
        except:
            print("No __del__ method")

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        self.driver.get(request.url)
        body = self.driver.page_source
        print(body)
        return HtmlResponse(self.driver.current_url, body=body, encoding='utf-8', request=request)
    def parse(self,response):
        print(response.text)

        self.driver.quit()

process = CrawlerProcess({'LOG_LEVEL':'INFO',
                        })
process.crawl(TestSpider)
process.start()
```

The problem I am having is that `process_request` isn't being called when a request is made by scrapy.
How can I manipulate how Scrapy handles requests so that I don’t make two requests, one through Scrapy and one through Selenium.

Comment: `process_request` needs to be in  middlewares

Comment: See https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium

Answer (score 0):

Amjasd.
**wishmaster** is totally right, you should use Download middleware and put Selenium there. But it's not a good idea, because in this case, you crawler will be synchronous. A better idea is to use Splash or Splash cluster which colled [Aquarium](https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/aquarium)